# Simple problem with planes and angles

Tags: geometry, vectors

I know that the dihedral angle between two planes is given by the angle between its two normal vectors but why is that true?

Below is my sketch that shows what I try to do when presented with this problem.

[image]

Given the fact that I stated at the beginning, $\theta_2$ must necessarily be the dihedral angle but I initially thought that $\theta_1 = π - \phi$ is the dihedral angle. What is it about the definition of the dihedral angle that makes it so that $\theta_2$ is the dihedral angle? Why is it not $\theta_1$?

Comment: Consider two lines, with a common point on the line of intersection of the two planes, with one line in each plane, and such that each of the two lines is perpendicular to the line of intersection. The angle between the two planes is the same as the angle between the two lines.

Comment: By _definition_, the angle between two intersecting planes is the angle between the normal vectors. My previous comment was intended provide some motivation.

Comment: The usual motivation is this: If you rotate each plane so that each new plane is perpendicular to the original, then whatever the angle was should be unchanged. Hence the normal vectors can be used to represent each of the new planes.

Comment: If the angle between normals is $\theta$, dihedral angle can be taken as $\theta$ or $\pi - \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the dihedral angle between two planes is equal to $\phi$, the angle between the two corresponding normal vectors of those two planes.

[image]

Note that $\phi = \phi ‘$ and $\theta_2 = \phi ‘$ because $\theta_2$ is the exterior angle of the cyclic quadrilateral circumscribed by the blue circle.

Of course, we can use $\phi_1$ as the angle between the two normal vectors. In that case $\theta_1$ will be taken as the dihedral angle. (Refer to another comment).

One common approach is to select the one that is acute so that the cosine of it will give a positive result.